# How to search in a JSON element?

Tags: elasticsearch

I am using elasticsearch 7 and I have stored following index:

PUT myindex

```
{
    "id": 2,
    "price": {"amount":10.0, "currency": "EUR"},
    "folders": ["Book", "Newspaper"]
}
```

and I want to create two queries:

- to sort all elements by price (no interest in currency)
- to look for all elements with "Book" as
  folder.

I tried to map a new index by using the following:

```
{
    "settings" : {
        "index" : {
            "sort.field" : ["price.amount", "price.currency"], 
            "sort.order" : ["asc", "asc"] 
        }
    },
    "mappings": {
        "properties": {
            "price": {
                "type": "keyword"

            },
            "currency": {
                "type": "keyword"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

but I got following error:

```
{
  "error": {
    "root_cause": [
      {
        "type": "resource_already_exists_exception",
        "reason": "index [myindex/1dsbGhj3RSCwm8Yad6oPOA] already exists",
        "index_uuid": "1dsbGhj3RSCwm8Yad6oPOA",
        "index": "myindex"
      }
    ],
    "type": "resource_already_exists_exception",
    "reason": "index [myindex/1dsbGhj3RSCwm8Yad6oPOA] already exists",
    "index_uuid": "1dsbGhj3RSCwm8Yad6oPOA",
    "index": "myindex"
  },
  "status": 400
}
```

thanks for any help

**UPDATE**

@LeBigCat here a sample of a list of documents for which I would like to create the queries:

PUT myindex2

```
{
    "id": 2,
    "price": {"amount":10.0, "currency": "EUR"},
    "folders": ["Book", "Newspaper"]
},
{
    "id": 3,
    "price": {"amount":15.0, "currency": "EUR"},
    "folders": ["Book"]
},
{
    "id": 4,
    "price": {"amount":3.0, "currency": "EUR"},
    "folders": ["Plant"]
},
{
    "id": 5,
    "price": {"amount":3.0, "currency": "USD"},
    "folders": []
}
```

Comment: You cant update mapping of an existing index. As you already PUT a document, elastic created a mapping for it. You need to delete your index (or create a new one with a different name). The sort will be in the search querry, not in the settings. Please share us 2-3 documents and we would be able to create your querries.

Comment: @LeBigCat note that it is possible to define [index-time sorting](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/index-modules-index-sorting.html) when creating an index. But the rest is true, the OP needs to delete the index and recreate it.

Comment: @Val: thanks for the tips, didnot know this feature.

Comment: @LeBigCat cool, that feature has been around (in beta) since ES 6.0 and went GA in ES 6.5.

Comment: I updated post with some documents as requested by @LeBigCat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use this query:

```
{
    "sort": [{
        "price.amount": {
            "order": "asc"
        }
    }],
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [{
                "match": {
                    "folders": "Book"
                }
            }]
        }
    }
}
```